# Sequelize - Calling a beforeDestroy hook on instance that has onDelete Cascade

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a scenario involving two tables (one-to-many), where a user can delete a record or array of records from the first table (name: document, relationship: one) and then the record(s) associated to that table from my second table (name: file, relationship: many) will be removed. The `onDelete` cascading on the "file" table is working as it should, but my hook is never firing.

- Do I need to call the hook somewhere within my `.destroy` sequelize
  method?
- Because my relationship one-to-many where a user can have multiple
  files or a single file for one document, do I need to add hooks for
  both `beforeDestroy` and `beforeBulkDestroy`?

**Here is the association between the two tables:**

**Document**

```
var Document = sequelize.define('document', {
    ...
},
{
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Document.hasMany(db.File, { foreignKey: 'document_id'}),
        }
    }
});
return Document;
```

**File**

```
var File = sequelize.define('file', {
    ...
},{
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
        beforeDestroy: function(whereClause, fn){
            //options.individualHooks = true;
            console.log('whereClause Start');
            console.log(whereClause);
            console.log('fn start');
            console.log(fn);
        },
        beforeBulkDestroy: function(whereClause, fn) {
            //options.individualHooks = true;
            console.log('whereClause Start');
            console.log(whereClause);
            console.log('fn start');
            console.log(fn);   
        }
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            File.belongsTo(db.Document, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true});
        }
    }
});
return File;
```

**Only Sequelize trigger scenario:**

```
models.Document.destroy({
    where: {
        userId: req.user.userId,
        documentId: documentId //Replace with array in certain instances
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem. Because documentation (v5):

> Note: You can't use hooks with instances. Hooks are used with models.

and

> Instance Hooks: The following hooks will emit whenever you're editing a **single object**

giving very mixed view I decided to not destroy by instances `models.Document.destroy(where)`, but by models (Select model and then `document.destroy()`). Hooks are fired when doing so.

Seems that Sequelize (v5) is just not able to call hooks when you using `cascades` right now.

Answer (score 0):

The `Model.destroy()` method doesn't invoke the `beforeDestroy` hook by default. You can force it to do so with the `individualHooks: true` option, like so

```js
models.Document.destroy({
    where: {
        userId: req.user.userId,
        documentId: documentId //Replace with array in certain instances
    },
    individualHooks: true
})
```

See:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10270

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#model-hooks

If you want, you could alternatively jimmy-rig any bulk destroy on this model to always fire the individual hooks. This can be done via the `beforeBulkDestroy` hook:

```js
    beforeBulkDestroy: async (options) =>
        (options.individualHooks = true),
```

But of course this can be intensive and may not be desired behaviour.